# import a function from the parent directory `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'`

Tags: python, path

I'm in a directory called src and src has two directories:

```
src
  /apples
    /my_file.py
  /carrots
functions.py
```

functions.py contains functions used by scripts within both apples and carrots directories.

At the top of my_file.py I initially tried to import functions but got an error 'no module named functions'.

I now understand that it's because it was in another directory, in this case just in src.

From looking at similar posts I tried this at the top of my_file.py, *bearing in mind that the working directory when calling my_file.py via a shell script is the directory src*:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/apples'))
```

I added a empty file **init**.py to /src per some responses on similar posts.

No matter what I try Python keeps telling me there is no module named functions.

I prefer a relative path since I'll be sharing this code with others and functions.py will always be in the directory above where my_file.py is.

How can I import src/functions.py within /src/apples/my_script.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Your problem is because the functions file is not in the path when searching from `myfile` it looks only for files in same directory as it

The problem is with  statement to call functions file you should use it relative to myfile and not current directory

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried that now but got the same outcome. Note My current working directory is src/. The file functions.py is also within this same directory src. I'm calling a shell script from within src that in turn calls my_file.py `./apples/run_local.sh`

Comment: So in other words I'm appending the path where functions.py does not exist. I tried amending your code to the following: `sys.path.append('../')` but still failed :/

Comment: Sorry I thought you wanted my file from functions will edit